# Using ngxs Selectors in Components

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am using ngxs with Angular and right now when I am trying to fetch changes from the store I define a selector in the state

```
@Selector()
static getData(state : DataStateModel){
    return state.data;
}
```

and in the component I use the @Select decorator to get an observable

```
@Select(DataState.getData) data$;
```

The trouble I am having is that if I have to access this data in the component, I will subscribe to the data$ observable and save the data to a new variable in the component.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.datasubscription = this.data$.subscribe( data => {this.componentVar = data});
}
```

This requires me to manually unsubscribe. Is this the correct way to implement this? Are there any inbuilt functions or third party plugins that can help cleanup this part?
I have also tried.

```
store.snapshot()
```

Comment: It's preferable to not manually subscribe in your component if you can avoid it - if you are just using `componentVar` to display the data in the component template then you are better off using `data$` directly in the template with the `async` pipe.  Then Angular will handle the subscription lifecycle for you.

Comment: I have done that. But what happens when I have to react to changes in $data in the component? like running some validation or toggle a variable? in this case I will have to subscribe in the component right?

Comment: You don't _have_ to subscribe in the component .. I'll add an answer with sample code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to manage a subscription in the component code you could use the Observable from the `Select` decorator to compose a new Observable chain e.g. in this example `dataChanged$`.  In this observable via the `rxjs` `tap` operator you could run some validation or toggle a variable etc as you described in the comments.

```
@Select(DataState.getData) data$;

dataChanged$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() { 

 this.dataChanged$ = this.data$.pipe(
    tap(result => // do something)
 );
}
```

Then in your template, subscribe to `$dataChanged` via the `async` pipe.

The other option of course is to manually unsubscribe when `ngOnDestroy` is called for this component.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by injecting store to the component

```
data$;

constructor(private store: Store) {
   this.data$ = this.store.select(DataState.getData)
                          .pipe(tap(data => {this.componentVar = data} )))
}
```

Pros: You don't need to create another observable variable

Cons: You won't be able to use @Select decorator.